# Drupal Commerce product in-cart status info in Views

Tags: 7, views, commerce

How can I use information in Views about whether a particular product is in this user's cart? Particularly, how many times into a Views row for that product?

For example, on a view listing available products, I'd like to be able to stylistically differentiate the rows representing products the customer has already added to their cart, and/or show a field, empty by default, stating how many of that item are already in the user's cart.

I've looked at existing Commerce modules such as [Commerce Views Display](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_views_display) and [Commerce Add to Cart Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras), but can't see anything directly relevant. I'm not sure how to proceed with creating something to do this short of writing a custom Views query which also loads the Commerce cart for each row, which I'd rather not do since I'm not sure how I could make it reasonably efficient.

Does anything exist to support this, or if not, is there a simpler/more integrated, less "reinventing the wheel" approach using the Views and/or Commerce API?

---

An ideal result would be a Views Field for commerce products outputting a simple number representing how many times a product with this product ID is in the cart. Turning that into all the above use-cases is easy (e.g. rewrite as a class `product-in-cart-N` then apply default styles to `.product-in-cart-0`, simply display the field with a label, etc etc).

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any modules, that will provide the functionality that you described out of the box, but the snippets below will probably get you moving in the right direction.

---

You'd write a function that gets all product IDs that are in the cart.

```
/**
 * Return the product_id values for all products in the cart
 *
 * @return
 *  An array of product ids
 */
function CUSTOMMODULE_get_products_in_cart() {
  $cart_product_ids = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);

  if (!isset($cart_product_ids)) {
    global $user;
    $cart_product_ids = array();
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
    if ($order) {
      $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
      foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
                if ($line_item_wrapper->type->value() == 'product') {
                    $product_wrapper = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product;
                    $cart_product_ids[] = $product_wrapper->product_id->value();
                }
      }
    }
        $unique_cart_product_ids = array_unique($cart_product_ids);
  }

  return $cart_product_ids;
}
```

---

For adding a class to the views row according to the quantity in the cart you'd implement **`hook_views_pre_render()`** and implement your logic there

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function CUSTOMMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view_name') {
        // get product_ids in cart
        $cart_product_ids = CUSTOMMODULE_get_products_in_cart();
        if (in_array($product->product_id, $cart_product_ids)) {
            // check how many times product_id is in the present in the array
            // do other stuff - apply class, etc.
        }
  }
}
```

---

Also, you'd probably want to change the "Add to Cart" button text to something custom if the product is already in the cart

```
function CUSTOMMODULE_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $cart_product_ids = CUSTOMMODULE_get_products_in_cart();
    if (in_array($product->product_id, $unique_cart_product_ids)) {
        // Product is already in cart
        // Change "Add to Cart" button text
        $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Add one more'); // your custom text and maybe a quantity of that product that is already in cart...
    }
}
```

---

I think using `hook_views_pre_render()` is the right way to go about this, but if there is more efficient or easier way I'd like for others to pitch in with ideas.

Hope this helps.